# Mysql failure packages

Tags: mysql

> root@dedi-fr-36189:~# apt-get install mysql-server Reading package
>   lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information...
>   Done Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
>   been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to
>   resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libglib2.0-0 :
>   Recommends: xdg-user-dirs
>                   Breaks: glib-networking (< 2.33.12) but 2.32.3-1 is to be installed  mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not
>   going to be installed E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated
>   breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

Any ideas how to solve this? Im not to good in linux :p

Answer (score 1):

Fixed,

> apt-get install xdp-user-dirs 
>   apt-get install glib_networking